# Running a report through Google Ad Manager API with an xml request that includes dimension attributes

Tags: xml, api, google-ad-manager, boomi

I have a process in Boomi that can pull data from the GAM API. I've been using it to pull dimensions and columns, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to pull dimension attributes.

When I add it to the xml request to run the report, I get this error:
Failed processing original documents i1i in the Mogo Google Ad Manager Connection - Line Item Pacing connector: com.boomi.connector.api.ConnectorException: Error code: soap:Client  Error message: Unmarshalling Error: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v202011":columns}'. One of '{"https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v202011":dimensionAttributes, "https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v202011":customFieldIds, "https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v202011":cmsMetadataKeyIds, "https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v202011":customDimensionKeyIds, "https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v202011":startDate, "https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v202011":endDate, "https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v202011":dateRangeType, "https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v202011":statement, "https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v202011":adxReportCurrency, "https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v202011":timeZoneType}' is expected.

This is the xml I'm using:

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<runReportJob xmlns="https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v202011">
  <reportJob>
    <reportQuery>
    <dimensions>DATE</dimensions>
    <dimensions>LINE_ITEM_NAME</dimensions>
    <dimensionAttributes>LINE_ITEM_LIFETIME_IMPRESSIONS</dimensionAttributes>
    <columns>TOTAL_LINE_ITEM_LEVEL_IMPRESSIONS</columns>
      <startDate>
        <year>'{6}'</year>
        <month>'{5}'</month>
        <day>'{4}'</day>
      </startDate>
      <endDate>
        <year>'{3}'</year>
        <month>'{2}'</month>
        <day>'{1}'</day>
      </endDate>
    </reportQuery>
  </reportJob>
</runReportJob>'
```

It works fine without the dimension attribute line, but it won't even run when I add that. Is there something wrong with the syntax? I based it off this:
https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/reference/v202108/ReportService.ReportQuery

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a schema validation issue. You must respect the order of the XML fields (it's an xsd sequence.

Try this :

> ```
> '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <runReportJob xmlns="https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v202011">
>   <reportJob>
>     <reportQuery>
>     <dimensions>DATE</dimensions>
>     <dimensions>LINE_ITEM_NAME</dimensions>
>     <columns>TOTAL_LINE_ITEM_LEVEL_IMPRESSIONS</columns>
>     <dimensionAttributes>LINE_ITEM_LIFETIME_IMPRESSIONS</dimensionAttributes>
>     <startDate>
>       <year>'{6}'</year>
>       <month>'{5}'</month>
>       <day>'{4}'</day>
>     </startDate>
>     <endDate>
>       <year>'{3}'</year>
>       <month>'{2}'</month>
>       <day>'{1}'</day>
>     </endDate>
>     </reportQuery>
>   </reportJob>
> </runReportJob>'
> ```

[image]

WSDL : https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v202011/ReportService?wsdl

Comment: The one post that mentions that the order of elements is important! This fixed my `cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element` error.